# Wordpress header and footer in Vbulletin problem

Tags: php

So im working in a project that will have Wordpress has the main page and then vbulletin as a forum. I already connected both platforms with a plugin so the users can login either in wordpress or in vbulletin.

Now for the design part, I want the vbulletin forum page to have the wordpress header and footer, searched on google and found that that can be achieved by creating a plugin/hook in vbulletin like this:

```
ob_start();
include( '../wp-load.php');
include('../wp-content/themes/Avada/header.php');
$wp_header = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

after that just insert '$wp_header' in vbulletin header file.

Problem is nothing happens, all I get is '$wp_header' written on top of my vbulletin page.

I have my wordpress installed in a folder 'apostasgreen',
and vbulletin in the folder 'apostasgreen/forum'. 
maybe my file paths are wrong?

Any help in this? thanks

Comment: What is the exact command you are putting in your vbulletin page? If what I think is correct, you need to put `echo $wp_header`, but you have to be sure that $wp_header is written before using it

Comment: What this essentially would do is to, not only boot up and run vbulletin application, but it would also boot up and run Wordpress application on every request to vbullitin. That's a lot or resources...

Comment: in my vbulletin default theme header file i just write:

    $wp_header , I tried with 'echo' now and nothing happens!

Comment: I found a post about this and changed the code, now actually something shows up:
        'ob_start();  
        include('../wp-load.php');  
        include('../wp-content/themes/Avada/header.php');  
        $wp_header= ob_get_contents();  
        ob_end_clean();  

        $preRegister['wp_header'] = $wp_header;  
        vB_Template::preRegister('header', $preRegister);'  

also on vbulletin theme header file I added: {vb:raw $wp_header}.
now, the header actually shows up but with some css problems, maybe I have a problem with css paths by linking the files this way?